# No puedo utilizar variables de un script de HTML, en un script de Python

Tags: python

Cordial saludo.
En la actualidad estoy muy interesado en aprender Python, es por ello que tome la decisión de cambiarle de lenguda a un sitio web que desarrolle en PHP y lo estoy pasando a Python.
Primero tengo este índex:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DatosUsuario</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Datos usuario</h2> 
    <form method="post" action="ValidacionUsuario2.py">
      usuario: <input type="text" name="usuario" size="30" /> <p />
      clave: <input type="password" name="clave" size="10" /> <p />
      <input type="submit" value="ejecutar" />
    <form/>
  </body>
</html>
```

como pueden notar, este índex utilizara el script ValidacionUsuario2.py, el cual necesitara los variables usuario y clave. Es por ello que las dejo disponibles utilizando el método POST. En ValidacionUsuario2.py pienso hacer una validación sencilla para ver si todo funciona correctamente, este es el contenido actual del script:

```
from index import usaurio,clave
if usario=="123" and clave="123":
    print("bienvenido")
else: 
    print("valida el usuario y la contraseña ya que no son correctos")
```

Al ejecutar el índex, dando clic en el botón ejecutar, me devuelve una pagina mostrando exactamente el código que escribí, como sino hubiera sido interpretado.
Que debo hacer para que mi código sea interpretado y se ejecute correctamente las validaciones?

Comment: Por lo pronto tienes algunos "gazapos", como son: `import usaurio` y `usario=="123"` y `and clave="123"`.

Comment: El servidor no interpreta directamente un script de Python, al menos no como sucede con PHP. Tu aplicación debe estar escrita de tal manera que al intentar acceder a la ruta especificada se ejecute el intérprete.

Comment: En realidad, es peor... el servidor web que pongas tiene que saber que lenguaje tiene por debajo para poder traducir eso a requerimientos web. Para usar PHP, seguramente instalaste un apache que sabe como interpretar PHP... googlea sobre lo mismo, pero para python.. tenes que hacer muchisimas mas cosas para qeu funcione...

Comment: De acuerdo con los comentarioa anteriores. Por aportar algo mas. Te sugiero que te mire el módulo http.server para crearte un pequeño servidor web. Para aplicaciones mas sofisticadas prueba Flask o Django en ese orden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así como se requiere un servidor que "entienda" `PHP` para poder procesar archivos `.php`, se requiere un servidor que "entienda" `Python` para poder procesar archivos `.py`. Una opción para que tu servidor use `Python` es [Flask](https://flask-es.readthedocs.io/). Hay módulos de `Flask` para distintos servidores, como `apache` o `nginx`, por ejemplo. `Flask` incluye algunas funciones y decoradores para facilitar el procesamiento de una petición. Un ejemplo de cómo se vería un código en `Flask` que respondiera al formulario que tienes en la dirección `ValidacionUsuario2` de tu servidor es

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
aplicacion = Flask(__name__)

@aplicacion.route("/ValidacionUsuario2", methods=['POST'])
def ValidacionUsuario2():
    print('El usuario es ' + request.form.get('usuario')) #esto se mostrará sólo en el registro interno del servidor
    print('La clave es ' + request.form.get('clave'))     #esto se mostrará sólo en el registro interno del servidor
    
    return 'Estamos trabajando aún en la validación' #esta será la respuesta a la petición, que verá el cliente


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aplicacion.run()
```

Como puedes ver, esencialmente lo que se hace es escribir las funciones de `Python` que respondan a una petición, y luego se les agrega arriba un decorador.